# Problem with queries ith Q object ('works' but not all the time)

Tags: python, django, django-q

I use Q object in a search input area
I have many field to test in the search area so I use OR (|) in my query
Sometime it works, sometimes not
I mean, I test search on a field -> it work
I had new field in the query and it does'nt work anymore...

I check my code go back and test again but i do not understand what is wrong

```py
@login_required
def liste_participantes(request):
    """ A view to list participants. """

    liste_existe = True
    if request.POST:
        ide = request.POST.get('ide', False)
        try:
#           Participante.objects.get(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide)
            Participante.objects.get(
                Q(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide) | Q(pat_nom=ide) | Q(pat_pre=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_001=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_002=ide) | Q(pat_nai_dat=ide)
            )
        except:
            liste_existe = False
        else:
#           participantes = Participante.objects.filter(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide)
            participantes = Participante.objects.filter(
                Q(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide) | Q(pat_nom=ide) | Q(pat_pre=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_001=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_002=ide) | Q(pat_nai_dat=ide)
            )
    else:
        participantes = Participante.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'participante/liste_participantes.html', locals())
```

none of the fields works but if I suppress the last field (Q(pat_nai_dat=ide) and run again all fields works !!!

Comment: Can you please share your `models.py` so we can see which fields are which?

Comment: Lesson to you: __NEVER EVER use bare except clauses__.

Answer (score 0):

'''Python
class Participante(SafeDeleteModel):
    """ A class to create a participant instance. """

````
_safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
pat_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
pat_ide_prn_cse = models.CharField("Identifiant Princesse",
    max_length=14,
    validators = [
        RegexValidator(
            regex='^SP[M|F][0-9]{11}$',
            message= 'L\'identifiant doit être au format requis',
            code='invalid_participant_id'
        ),
    ],
    unique=True
    )
pat_inc_dat = models.DateField("Date d'inclusion")
pat_nom = models.CharField("Nom", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_pre = models.CharField("Prénom", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_pti_nom_001 = models.CharField("Surnom / Petit nom", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_pti_nom_002 = models.CharField("Second petit nom (optionnel)", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_nai_dat = PartialDateField("Date de naissance(YYYY-MM-JJ ou YYYY-MM ou YYYY)",
    default=None)
pat_inc_age = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
pat_ide_apr = models.CharField("Numéro patient interne Aprosam", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_ide_phv = models.CharField("Numéro national Population HautementVulnérable(PHV)",
    max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_ide_pvh = models.CharField("Numéro national PVVIH", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_lie_hab = models.CharField("Lieu d'habitation", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_con_nom = models.CharField("Nom Prénom", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_con_adr = models.CharField("Adresse", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_con_tel_001 = models.CharField("Téléphone 1", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_con_tel_002 = models.CharField("Téléphone 2", max_length=100, blank=True)
pat_not_opt = models.CharField("Notes", max_length=2000, blank=True)```
````

Comment: Please move this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your *try-except* you are not specifying the exception type, so any error is caught. What's probably happening is that for some inputs an error is raised and sneakily caught by the generic `except`.

What I guess you want to catch is `Partecipante.DoesNotExist`, raised when the query doesn't produce any results, so try to change you code like this and see what happens:

```py
try:
   # ...
except Partecipante.DoesNotExist:
   # ...
else:
   # ...
```

Also, seems to me the purpose of your *try-except-else* block is to verify whether your search produces any results or not, you can simplify it like this:

```py
participantes = Participante.objects.filter(
    Q(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide) | Q(pat_nom=ide) | Q(pat_pre=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_001=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_002=ide) | Q(pat_nai_dat=ide)
)
if not participantes:
    liste_existe = False
```

In this way you query your database only once.

Comment: I try the second colution that seems better but I have an error of type: ["'SPF20191001001' is not a valid date string (YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD)"] when I try to search for "SPF20191001001"

Comment: problem comes with date

Comment: Moreover, when I read the Q object documentation, Q(pat_ide_prn_cse=ide) should be equivalent to pat_ide_prn_cse like ide% but it does'nt seems to be the case because if I search with the begining of items (e;g. SPF2019) no results are return even if 2 records should be returned...

Comment: sorry I di not read correctly the doc and forgot __startswith function for the "like comportment"

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using regular expression for date
thanks to bug for his help

```
@login_required
def liste_participantes(request):
    """ A view to list participants. """

    liste_existe = True
    if request.POST:
        ide = request.POST.get('ide', False)

        if re.match(r'^[0-9]{4}',ide):
            participantes = Participante.objects.filter(Q(pat_nai_dat=ide) | Q(pat_inc_datadmin=ide))
        else:
            participantes = Participante.objects.filter(Q(pat_ide_prn_cse__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_nom__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_pre__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_001__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_pti_nom_002__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_con_tel_001__startswith=ide) | Q(pat_con_tel_002__startswith=ide))
        if not participantes:
            liste_existe = False
    else:
        participantes = Participante.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'participante/liste_participantes.html', locals())
```

Comment: Dont use a POST request for search - POST are for updating the server's state, not for getting data. You want a GET request here. Also, dont pass `locals()` as context - it doesn't make clear which local variables are suppposed to be part of the template context, and I can garantee it _will_ break something at some point (when a local variable will override something from a contextmanager in your template's context for example), and then the poor soul having to fix the issue will want to kill you since he'll have no idea which of the local names were really intended to be part of the context.